# Não consigo adicionar um FlatButton á BottomNavigationBar no Flutter!

Tags: flutter

Eu estou fazendo uma BottomNavigationBar para meu app Flutter mas não consigo adicionar um Botão(FlatButton) á o BottomNavigation. Eu consigo adicioná-lo mas ele não aparece quando dou Run no App!

**Aqui está meu código**

```dart
import 'package:eeal/pages/profile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home.dart';

class Start extends StatefulWidget {
  const Start({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Start> createState() => _StartState();
}

class _StartState extends State<Start> {
  int currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    Home(),
    Profile(),
  ];

  Widget currentScreen = Home();

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: PageStorage(
      child: currentScreen,
      bucket: bucket,
    ));

    
    FlatButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      color: Colors.blue,
      onPressed: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você colocou o FlatButton após o retorno com Scaffold, o que torna o código do FlatButton um `DeadCode`.

Segundo, FlatButton é obsoleto há *MUITO* tempo, mude para TextButton e child Icon.

Código com BottomNavigationBar:

```dart
import 'package:eeal/pages/profile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home.dart';

class Start extends StatefulWidget {
  const Start({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Start> createState() => _StartState();
}

class _StartState extends State<Start> {
  int currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    Home(),
    Profile(),
  ];

  Widget currentScreen = Home();

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageStorage(
        child: currentScreen,
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          // index é qual item do BottomNavigationBar clicou,
          //TODO Navegação...
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Veja: (Documentação com exemplo)[https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html]

Você utiliza alguma IDE? Se usar o VS Code com plugin do Flutter veria que é dead code bem fácil, veja quando colei seu código no meu editor:
[image: Dead code]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).